# Internal Error when Restoring Odoo Database from PgAdmin4

Tags: database, postgresql, odoo, backup, pgadmin

How can I backup and restore an Odoo database using pgadmin?

To backup, I right clicked on the database, backup, use .tar format.

When I try to restore, Odoo says: `failed restored database`.
The database is there, but when I'm logged in, it shows internal error.

Comment: please provide the error message and traceback from odoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use PgAdmin to do the restore when you backup the database with PgAdmin.

Steps to restore database on PyAdmin

1. Create a new database
2. Right click the database, select restore
3. Choose the backup file
4. **Data/Objects** Tab -> Do not Save -> Owner
5. **Options** Tab -> Queries -> Clean
   Before restore
6. Restore

Make sure you have copy the filestore, and rename the folder same as the restored database name.